# How to implement a view to be shown before a Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbar

I am designing an iPhone app in which when the application first launches, it should show a login/password view that is not part of Tab Bar Controller. Once the user enters a valid password, they are taken to a standard Tab View with a Tab Bar as the root controller. My challenge is whether to do a Window-based application or to do a Tab Bar application when I first start the project.

I hope I am making sense.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with a Tab Bar app just fine.

In your appDelegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, right at the end, you'll add the login screen's viewController and pop it up on top of the tabs by simply adding two lines, like so:

```
[window addSubview:tabcontroller.view]; // Already present
initialScreenViewController = [[InitialScreenViewController alloc] init];
[window addSubview:initialScreenViewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible]; // Already present
return YES; // Already present
```

Because you're adding the `initialScreenViewController` (call it whatever you want, that's just an example) *after* the tab bar, it will appear above it (closer to the screen) in the window. When you're done with it you can dismiss it and your tabs and such will all be present.

---

**Edited to add**

Here's how to add it modally:

Instead of

```
[window addSubview:initialScreenViewController.view];
```

use

```
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:initialScreenViewController animated:NO];
[initialScreenViewController release];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716755/showing-login-view-controller-before-main-tab-bar-controller   would this approach be any advantageous?

Comment: @jini Hmm, works fine for me. I'll edit to change it to adding it as a modal view.

Comment: @Matthew you don't see the tabs visible at bottom? I can see the tab labels.

Comment: OK just tried it by doing it modally and now I do not see the tabs. Hmm very interesting that it would hide it now.