# Show login view controller before tab bar controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am new to iphone development. I am developing an iphone application which contains four tabs. I have implemented it using tab bar controller. But now i need to show a login screen without tabs before tab bar controller. I have tried so many methods but didnt get the one i wanted.

Can anyone pls explain how to do this with a code snippet??

Comment: I tried by adding view controller and added it as sub view and removed it from view controller...

Comment: Possible Duplicate of this question  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716755/showing-login-view-controller-before-main-tab-bar-controller][1]

Comment: I tried tat too... But it din work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new class LoginViewController. When your application launches then add the view to the window. Now when login is successful then remove it from superview and add the MainController.

Comment: I did what u said... Its working partially... that is loginview displaying first but tabbar is displaying bottom of the screen slightly.. How to hide it completely...?

Comment: [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
 
   loginViewController *loginView = [[loginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"loginViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 [window addSubview:loginView.view];
 in didfinishlaunching.. is this right??? and in loginviewcontroller      [self.view removeFromSuperview];... Any mistakes in this???

Comment: Adjust the size of your view.

Comment: self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);      Is this right

Comment: Yup if you have the status bar also.

Comment: Nothing happening even though i change those values :(

Comment: I have already pasted it... Displaying loginview by              [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
 
    // Add the tab bar controller's view to the window and display.
 loginViewController *loginView = [[loginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"loginViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 [window addSubview:loginView.view];                     Loading tab view by     [self.view removeFromSuperview];
 self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 560);               Is this enough????

Comment: What part of tab bar are you seeeing?

Comment: http://www.box.net/shared/0cdsl9mu7ktlf3dblfiq... Please check this image... I m getting this only...

Comment: Make the origin as 0,20 self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460);

Comment: You can accept my answer and i will update my post. The status bar is of size 320,20 and hence when you add to window which is parent container you need to offset accordingly.

Comment: I hope you got it now. Also you can learn about how to upvote answers and be more involved on stackoverflow. Its a great place to learn.

Comment: Exactly... Stackflow provides excellent opportunity for learners to learn more :) I upvoted the answer :)

Comment: @PraveenS i also want to do same that first my login screen will be displayed & after that tab is shown. & i have tried above everything but i got 1 problem that my tab is not working.on clicking on tabs nothing happens.i.e no tab is not changing..plz can u help me..:(

Comment: @Sweety Can you post some of your code in a new question or in a chat room.

Comment: NSArray *viewControllersArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:nav1, nav2, nav3,nav4,nav5, nil];
self.tabbar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[self.tabbar setViewControllers:viewControllersArray animated:YES]; [self.window addSubview:tabbar.view];//tabbar with 5 diffrent tabs
[self.window addSubview:nav6.view];//nav6 is my login screen 
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: @Praveen S  from this first tym login screen is displayed & after success it is showing tabbar..i.e in my login file on success i have just write [self.view removeFromSuperview]//it is showing tab bar but tab is not working only..:(

Comment: You need to add the self.tab.view to the window after you complete login. Also where are you calling the above code from? Its better you create a chat room or write a new question with formatted code.

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of UITabBarController (though it's not advised by apple), but for this purposes it should be ok and do this in viewWillAppear

```c
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    BOOL isLogged in = //do something to determine if you're logged in
    if(!loggedIn){
        LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewControllerNibHere" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:YES]; //or NO if you don't want it animated
        [loginViewController release];
    }
}
```

Or add this to a category for UITabBarController and import it in the app delegate or wherever you're using the UITabBarController

Comment: I tried it... It is navigating to login view as expected but while returning to tab view tabs are not displaying... I think i donno to return back after login... I used the following code to return to tab view: FirstViewController *tabView = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
 [self presentModalViewController:tabView animated:NO];
 [tabView release]; Is this right???

Comment: How are you setting the view controllers for each tab? If you're setting them in code, do the following thing in viewDidLoad; FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewControllerNibHere.." bundle:nil]; then self.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstViewController,secondViewController(if you have one), nil];

Comment: Oh, also, when you are done with your login, you don't present another view controller modally, you dismiss the modal view controller by calling [self dismissModalViewController]; in your loginViewController once you're done with your login.

Comment: Actually i m setting view controllers for tabs using IB only... Am getting error when used [self dismissModalViewController] :( ...

Comment: Can you zip your thing and send it to me to take a look, there are a bunch of things that could be wrong..

Comment: Actually hang on for a minute, I'll send you something :)

Comment: http://bit.ly/ndtvJv enjoy. I made it a bit differently. Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Cool Man its working perfectly... Seriously i cant understand the structure fully (Since i m a newbie)... But i m goin to use this in my project :) Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new UIViewController subclass with a nib that represents your login screen (I'll refer to it as SignInViewController).
- Open your MainWindow.nib file and add a new UIViewController
- Set the new UIViewController's class type to SignInViewController
- Set the UIWindow's rootViewController outlet to the new SignInViewController
- Now create a new nib file and copy your existing UITabBarController to it (it's best to split nibs rather than having a single-mega nib)
- Back in your MainWindow.xib change the existing UITabBarController's attributes to specify the nib name that you just created

Comment: I did first five points... But cant understand the last one.. UITabbarController attributes means???

Answer (score 0):

Check this Link's source code,

it uses Login Controller as modal view with 4 tabs

http://code.google.com/p/tweetero/source/checkout

Also i tried this way ,

in my first tab view - in `viewDidAppear` - i'll check Login = YES then

show the `LoginController`

```
- [self.tabbarcontroller presentMOdalViewcontroller:LoginView animated:YES];
```

so every time u click on first tab - if u need to Login put a flag - check it & show Login View

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Actually i dont want to display the tabs before user login... Anyway thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create a new LoginViewController as other people have mentioned and then set your rootviewController to tabBarcontroller as soon as you authenticate the user. Here is how you can do this in swift, this is snippet to put as soon you authenticate your user in LoginViewController

```
let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
```

Where TabBarController is the storyboard id of your tab bar controller. It could be anything whatever name you have given it.