# How to open a ViewController before application starts in iOS

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

I am working in iOS 5,and before loading my application,I want to open a another view controller,where the user should enter some data,for eg.password and when the password matches ,application will be opened,I am not getting how to do this..I tried some code ,which I have written below

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    if(somecondition)
    {       
        ViewController *View =[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]; 
        [_window addSubview:View.view];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

But I dont know whether it is a right way,so friends,please help me out..

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: I edited the answer, and maybe it's what you really want now. :)

Comment: hey no kjuly..I already got my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create some `bool` variable for checking is this a first start or another. The best place to store this `bool` is NSUserDefaults. Well, if this is a first start then show your LoginViewController, if not - execute regular code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 
    UIViewController *startVC = nil;

    if (isFirstLaunch){
        startVC = [[[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }
    else{
        startVC = [[[WorkspaceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WorkspaceView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }

    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:startVC];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.window addSubview:navController.view];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: hey beryllium,in my if condition,I wrote this line of code [self.window setRootViewController:yourViewController] and it opens a view controller,but now after entering this view controller,how shall I start my app ,any suggestions

Comment: [[(YourDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:yourAnotherViewController];

Comment: hey but i dont have any view controller,I created my application by selecting the option "Tab Bar application" in iOS 5

Comment: tab bar is view controller as well.

Comment: but I am not able to call that TabBar...?How to call it

Comment: in iOS 5 their is no declaration of TabBarController

Comment: @Ranjit if you set your TabBarController as the rootViewController, you can dispatch it by `YourCustomTabBarController * tabBarController = (YourCustomTabBarController *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];`(Just like @beryllium suggested), then use any method you want.

Comment: @Ranjit your UITabBarController is init with `xib` file if you "selecting the option 'Tab Bar application' in iOS 5 ". You can create a `IBOutlet UITabBarController * tabBarController`, then point it to your TabBarController in your Interface Builder.

Comment: Hey thanks Kjuly ,but I am confused,you tell me how can I call tabbarcontroller which will start my app

Comment: hey Kjuly..did you mean this way......    UITabBarController *tabBarcontroller = (UITabBarController *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
    
    [[(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:tabBarcontroller];

Answer (score 4):

You should use

```
[self.window setRootViewController:yourViewController]
```

instead of `addSubview` to your window.
BTW, searching before asking is a good habit. ;)

---

If you want to show a view like the loginView or loadingView, you can set it as your rootViewController, when did loaded, you can reset your rootViewController.
Note, in your ProjectAppDelegate.m, you can get `window`
by `self.window`, and in other child view controller's, you'll need

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window]
```

to get your main window.

**Another simple way** to meet your requirement is that you can just present a `modalView` before showing your app. Dismiss it after done and then start your app.

You can get more suggestion [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716755/showing-login-view-controller-before-main-tab-bar-controller).

---

BTW, I'm sorry I didn't get your comments' notification when you are write at other users comment area a few days ago. :( You should add `@` before the user's name when you comment at somewhere else.

Comment: @Ranjit you also need add `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` before `return YES;`. You'll see the demo in the default `view based application` project of xCode.

Comment: @Ranjit `File` -> `New Project` -> `Application` -> `Single View Application`.

Comment: hey in iOS5 that all is not needed  and by you one line code above I am able to open the view controller,before my app starts.now I want to know..after entering that view how can I star my app

Comment: @Ranjit Is not needed in iOS5.0? I'm sorry.:p But only for iOS5? Compatible for iOS4.0 is necessary I think. ;)

Comment: @Ranjit did you mean run the test app??? `Cmd + B` to build and `Cmd + R` to run. Maybe I misunderstood.. :P

Comment: no Kjuly..look,before starting my app I wanted to open a view controller,so as you said ,I wrote this line of code [self.window setRootViewController:yourViewController] in applicationlaunching and it works,now from the opened view controller,how shall I open my app

Comment: I'm sorry @Ranjit but I still not clear about "open my app". If you want to push new views to your app, you need set `UINavigationViewController` as your rootViewController instead of a common `UIViewController`, and then dispatch `pushViewController:animated:` whenever you want. You can layout some buttons, etc; But if you want to switch different view by some tabs, you need `UITabBarController`.

Comment: you are not getting it my friend