# Switch between view without closing view xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, authentication, view, switch-statement

I have a Login interface, user interface, and a Main menu.

When I'm logging in, I switch on my user interface.

if I do a UIModalTransition, and if I come back to the page, I need to RE-login again, it's a problem for me.

I search a method for Switch between view but don't close them, because if you closed them, views restart, it's the same for UIWebview, I would like to switch between views without closed and reset views.

Is it possible ? 
I don't really know what kind of Code is it.

If you have ideas, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pushViewController` ie..

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourUserInterFaceViewController animated:YES];`   for transition between login and user interface.

Comment: I used the UIModalViewController, but everytime we need to Close the last view, otherwise the app Crash... :(
The same for pushViewController :(

Answer (score 0):

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357701/dynamic-first-view-controller-in-ios/12358841#12358841) answer i tried to explain the view controllers orchestration as i see it.

The idea is to create the manager class taking care of elements storage and presentation. It also mentions the way to manage the login information.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 3 ways

1)pushing the view into `UINavigationController`

2)presenting the view with ModalViewController

3)adding subView to rootViewController and remove it using `removeFromSuperView` when needed.

(you can allocate them when app launches and access them using

`[YourAppDelegate sharedApplication].yourViewController`)

Since your appDelegate is a singleTon class it will always return the same viewcontroller you've allocated at the time of launching the app. You can use Lazy Load also.

May be this will help.