# How to keep a tabbar in UIViewController in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I m very much new to iPhone development and strucked at a point .I have a UIViewController in which Im placing a tab bar and tab bar items(Search,Login) on it ..Now on startig up of the app how can I keep Search tabbaritem selected?.And If I click on login it has to redirect to another UIViewController(Login).But in UIViewController I dont need the tabbar.How can I make tab bar item to respond when login is clicked and redirect to some other view...?

Comment: if you want to show login viewcontroller and after login the tabbar controller should appear, your question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716755/showing-login-view-controller-before-main-tab-bar-controller

Comment: No what I need is first in a UIViewController I have to provide a tabbar .then if login tabbar item is pressed it has to redirect to loginviewcontroller ..How to make login tabbar item to respond and redirect to loginviewcontroller if it is clicked ?

Comment: Please check this link which has all the beginner examples. Try tabbarcontroller example http://fromideatoapp.com/downloads/example/

Answer (score 0):

From your question. It's clear that you don't need tabbar. Instead add tabbarcontroller.

Check the image I've attached . That will show you the overlay about what you should follow. 
[image: You just need to add tabbarcontroller from nib objects. Then add your viewcontrollers for a given tab]

Let me know. If anything is unclear.

Enjoy programming.

Comment: No first I have creted a UIView application and placed some textfields and labels on it .Now I have to add a tabbar .Im doing it by dragging from library and adding tabbaar items.They are getting added.But what I want is the first tabbaritem to be selected on app startup bcoz the startup view is search view and first tabbar is also search?.Now when I click on second tabbar item 'Login'it has to redirect to another view 'LoginVieweController.Now how to rediret to another view when login tabbar item is selected?

Comment: So basically you want your LoginVieweController as & when app starts . then after clicking login button you need your tabbar. Correct?

Comment: No ..Let me explain u clearly..When app starts SearchViewController with UILabels and UItextFields and tabbar with two tabbar items(Search,Login) will appear with Search tabbar item selected.Now after the app appears when I click on Login tabbar then it should redirect to LoginViewController.In loginViewController I dont have any tabbar.I have only textfields and button..

Comment: did you assign your LoginVieweController as your second tabbar controller from nib?

Comment: ok. how you have assigned your searchviewcontroller as your first tabbar item?

Comment: No I have not.I donno these items how to do ?How to assign  searchviewcontroller as  first tabbar item and  LoginVieweController as your second tabbar controller from nib

Comment: ok. that's why I've attached this image.Instead of adding tabbar then tabbritem in it. can't you add tabbarcontroller?

Comment: But I have already placed labels and textfileds on the view .Now I guess I have to add them again to tabbarcontroller again if Im not wrong..

Comment: No. You don't need to add them again. As it already resides in your searchviewcontroller itself.

Comment: But if I drag and drop tabbar controller on the view I couldnot see it when I run the app

Comment: ok.Are you working with singleview application or with some other?

Comment: ok. So if you want tabbar throughout the app then add it on mainwindow.xib

Comment: I dont want it through out the app.I just want it on SearchViewController which apperas when app starts up

Comment: ok. then add tabbarcontroller in the nib where you are adding searchviewcontroller

Comment: suppose your searchviewcontroller launches directly from appdelegate then add t at mainwindow.xib. or if your searchviewcontroller loads from some viewcontroller's click event then add it there

Comment: Yes searchviewcontroller launches directly from appdelegate and I have added it to mainwindow.xib >But on running the app still I couldnot see it

Comment: ok. add tabbarcontroller in mainwindow.xib below your window. As you can see in image, mine tabbarcontroller is below my view while yours will be below window

Comment: k I have added it and can see it at the botto of window.But still when I run I couldnot see it at he bottom.Should I connnect anything elz like delegates ..?

Comment: yes give outlets to uitabbarcontrolles from appdelegate's .h file

Comment: K I got it .I can see now when I run the app.Can u please tell me how to redirect to another view when Login tabbar item is clicked ..?

Comment: see my attached image. Your nib should be like this.when you expand your tabbarcontroller . you should be able to see view controller - item. in first item name your searchviewcontroller class & its related nib name in its properties then follow the same steps for view controller item2 that would be your loginviewcontroller

Comment: But I couldnot see all those Objects -->I m unable to expand them .Mine is iPhone 4.3 simulator

Comment: np. though you should be able to see those. check again.

Comment: Sorry if Im asking many questions.But now when I try to keep cursor in textfield of SearchViewController ,I couldnot keep it ..Y ?

Comment: need to check your nib for that.

Comment: please refer http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-tabbar-uitabbarcontroller-tutorial/ . So you can get basics about uitabbarcontroller.

Comment: what couuld be the possible reason that i am unable to keep cursor in textfield of SearchViewController?

Answer (score 0):

On click to `login`,follow this code to get the application begin from LoginViewController without the tabBar..

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

appDelegate.window.rootViewController = LoginViewController;
```